# How can i send a file from multer to my website folder which is hosted on a server while multer is localhost

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, arrays

I want to upload a file through multer which is locally, Now i want to set the destination a multer to the upload folder of a website which is hosted on the server like GoDaddy or aws etc

Comment: You're looking to upload files to a remote location like an aws S3 bucket, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Don't mismatch your concept, localhost [mean](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/what-is-localhost) the ip of your system, so at server end it's a server ip which sense your api calls and handle that request. So multer is use to take your file and download it or copy file on your server, and the file is send from client side.
inshort client send it's file and server get that file process. the library which you are using is multer to handle file.